# Ignoring a signal on C

Tags: c, signals

This is not a question about code but theory.

I had this code before:

```
void handler(int signal){
    printf("Handler called\n");
}

struct sigaction act;
act.sa_handler = &handler;
act.sa_flags = 0;


if (sigaction(SIGINT, &act, NULL) < 0){
    exit(1);
}

if (sigaction(SIGQUIT, &act, NULL) < 0){
    exit(1);
}
```

When I was pressing `ctrl + C`, the handler was being called, but the program still exits.

And now, by curiosity, I tried changing the flags to `SA_RESTART`. Now it does not exit.

Why?

Comment: Please create a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SA_RESTART` causes `EINTR`-interruptible system calls (e.g., `read`) to be restarted after a handled signal is delivered.

So if you had:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>

void handler(int signal)
{
    printf("Handler called\n");
}

int main()
{
    struct sigaction act;
    act.sa_handler = &handler;
    act.sa_flags = 0;
    if (sigaction(SIGINT, &act, NULL) < 0){ exit(1); }
    char ch; ssize_t nr;
    nr=read(0,&ch,1);
}
```

then with `SA_RESTART` it'll be as if the `nr=read(0,&ch,1);` line had been replaced with

```
while(0>(nr=read(0,&ch,1)) && errno==EINTR){}`
```

Note that you should be calling only async-signal-safe functions in signal handlers. `printf` in a handler is normally a recipe for undefined behavior, though in this particular case where you're only interrupting code that is async-signal-safe itself (`read`), it is fairly safe, though the POSIX doesn't explicitly sanction it (AFAIK).

Comment: Yes I read somewhere the same thing about not calling printf since it is async.